# How transform string to recursive object?

Tags: javascript

I am passing a dot separated string into function

```
console.log( namespace('a.b.c.d.e'))
```

and expect get next result

```
//result => "{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":{}}}}}}"
```

my try (I don't know how to do it recursively)

```
const namespace = (string)=> {
  return string.split('.').reduce((acc,el)=>{
    acc[el] = {}
  },{})
}
```

Comment: I would probably use somethng like reduceRight to build the object from the inside-out:  `...reduceRight((acc,  prop) => ({[prop]: acc}),{})`

Comment: nice, It is exactly what I try to find, add this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = "a.b.c.d.e"

const output = input.split('.').reverse().reduce((acc,el)=>{
  return {[el]: acc}
},{})
  
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the below iteration approach :-

```js
function namespace(input){
let result = {};
let temp = result;
const inputArr = input.split(".");
inputArr.forEach((ele)=>{
  temp[ele] = {};
  temp = temp[ele];
})
return result;
}

console.log( namespace('a.b.c.d.e'))
```